# How do I get a SphereCollider's global origin in Unity?

Tags: unity, transformation, bounding-spheres

I've been following this tutorial: [Understanding Steering Behaviors: Collision Avoidance](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-steering-behaviors-collision-avoidance--gamedev-7777)

but I'm having trouble implementing one of the functions correctly in Unity, here's the code:

```
private function lineIntersectsSphere(ahd:Vector3, ahd2:Vector3, sphCol:SphereCollider) : boolean
{
    return distance(sphCol.center, ahd) <= sphCol.radius || distance(sphCol.center, ahd2) <= sphCol.radius;
}
```

The `SphereCollider` variable contains the `Center` variable, however, it always returns a vector containing `0, 0, 0` values. I imagine it's the spheres local origin.. is there a way to get the center? Perhaps it could be through the transform.position that the sphere is attached to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, colliders in Unity will be centered on the object's pivot point (given by `transform.position`). It's possible to configure a collider such that it's *not* centered -- in this case, that offset is given by the sphere's [`center`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SphereCollider-center.html) property, which is why you're seeing an offset of zero.

In *mooooost* cases, `transform.position` will be fine. If your sphere is offset from the pivot, though, you'll have to account for that:

```
Vector3 sphereCenter = transform.TransformPoint(sphCol.center);
```